# xcode different kinds of uiviewcontrollers in navigation controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I'm quite new with ios programming. I'm working with Master-Detail Application template and i want to change it a bit. First what i want to do is to change detail view for something what is in iphone version of sample code => in the first view there is a TableViewController, i select a row and ViewController with details is shown.
So i added a table to ViewController (notesList) which is created by template, i added new ViewController (notePreview) with class, added a seque Push between them, in a function didSelectRowAtIndexPath in notesList i'm creating a new instance of class for notePreview and i'm pushing it to self.navigationController. 
Unfortunetelly when i'm runing it on the simulator when i'm selecting a row from notesList new view is shown but that's only blank black screen, definitely not my notePreview. And what is strange for me, if instead of ViewController i'll chose TableViewController for notePreview everything works fine, the correct view is shown.
Any idea what i'm doing wrong? Is it impossible to switch in the same navigation controller from UITableView to UIView?

Some images to illustrate my problem

storyboard -> http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/692/screenshot20121102at258.png

notePreview -> http://img31.imageshack.us/img31/411/screenshot20121102at300.png

=================================================================================

using UIStoryBoard::instantiateViewControllerWithIdentified resolved problem but still i think there should be a better way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the parent class of that ViewController in the Storyboard scene is set to the VC class you have implemented.

[image: Custom Class Image]

Comment: Does that mean you checked it?

Comment: Yes i did. I even made a test: i added my VC - notePreview and some sample TableViewController and when indexPath.row == 1 than instead of notePreview i'm pushing on the views stack that TableViewController and ofcourse everything works fine for a Table but not for other view...